# If a website built without port 80, can other client access this website as usual?

Tags: http, port, httpserver

I know port 80 is one of well-know-port, but I am confused that if I build the website server process on other port except of 80, would it works when other client try to access this website server?

Comment: Of course.  Clients would just need to specify the port since it's not using the default/standard port.  Have you tried?  Did something not work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 80 is the default port for http. So connecting to http://domain would in essence send you to http://domain:80 (by default).

Port 443 is the default for https and would work the same way as stated for http above.

Any other port would require the you to do `url:port` to connect to. There are definitely ways to get around this (like forwarding) but I don't see the need for it and I think it causes more issues than anything.

You would also need to make sure that the new port is open, forwarded and can receive connections.

(Source for the first 2 paragraphs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Port)